# How to get foreign object with minimal price

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have two classes `Product` and `Offer`

```
class Product:
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class Offer:
    ...
    price = models.IntegerField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

And I have to get the offer of a product with minimal price in single queryset. I know that I can get price like this:

```
Product.objects.filter(...).annotate(minimal_price=Min('offer__price').values('minimal_price', ...)
```

or

```
product.offer_set.all().order_by('price').first()
```

But I have to get offer in single query with product like this:

```
Product.objects.filter(...).annotate(offer_with_minimal_price=Min('offer__price__but_return_offer_not_price').values('offer_with_minimal_price', ...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first object from the query

`Product.objects.filter(...).values('price').annotate(Min('price')).order_by('price')[0]`

I haven't checked this but it should work
You could also use

`Product.objects.filter(...).annotate(offer_with_minimal_price=Min('offer__price__but_return_offer_not_price').values('offer_with_minimal_price', 'id', ...).get(id=id)` to get the offer